# Passing ng-model from parent view to ng-include template

Tags: angularjs, templates

How can i pass a model defined in an controller to ng-include template?

For example: i have a model in my controller's $scope named "**account**". In the view i am referencing another template for address input.

the address template is below:

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-12">
        <label>Street Address</label>
        <textarea ng-model="physicalAddress.AddressLine1" class="form-control">dfdsf</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
        <label>Town / City</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="address.city">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
        <label>State / Region</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="address.region">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
        <label>Postal / Zip Code</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="address.postalCode">
    </div>
```

In the template above I want to add the **physicalAddress** object to my "account" model which is defined in the controller of parent view. The only way I see achieving this is by explicitly adding the address prefix **address.physicalAddress.AddressLine1**. However, this will defeat the purpose of having an template, because i want to be able to use the address template with other objects (shop,user etc).

is there any alternative way of achieving this?

Comment: Not really clear what the problem is ... although it's worth noting that `ng-include` creates a child scope. If you don't want that child scope use your own directive to include the form with

Comment: like @charlietfl said, if you want something you can reuse, you should create a directive.